# How can I get executionStats for aggregation in MongoDB 3.4.10?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I get MongoDB aggregation query execution time?

I tried this:

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate(
[ { '$match': { '$and': [ { 'meta.client_id': { '$eq': 1 } },
  { 'meta.is_deleted': { '$ne': 1 } } ] } },
  { '$group':
     { _id: '$Plant',
       value: { '$sum': 1 } } },
  { '$sort': { _id: 1 } } ]
)
```

But this is returning the stages `queryPlanner`, `winningPlan` and `rejectedPlans` not the ***executionStats***. I want to get query execution time in milliseconds.

Comment: What are your specific versions of MongoDB shell & server, as per `version()` and `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell? The `executionStats` explain verbosity mode is only supported for aggregation queries in MongoDB 3.6 or newer.

Comment: It's 3.4.10 mongo shell. But executionStats works perfectly fine for db.collection.find().explain("executionStats") with this version.

Comment: Yes, but `find` is a different command from `aggregate` ;-). Prior to MongoDB 3.6 explain for the `aggregate` command only supported the default `queryPlanner` verbosity and ignored any other options (see: [SERVER-19758](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to MongoDB 3.6, explain for the `aggregate` command only supported the default `queryPlanner` verbosity mode and ignored any other options (see: [SERVER-19758](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758)).

You'll need to upgrade your MongoDB server to 3.6 or newer in order to use [additional verbosity modes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#verbosity-modes) with `aggregate` commands.

Comment: How can I use `executionStats` mode with aggregation in MongoDB 4? `executionStats` mode works fine with `find` query but don't work with `aggregation`.

Comment: @qmn1711 I suggest posting a new question with details of your environment if this example doesn't work for you. In particular: what is the specific version of the application or driver you are using? I would start by testing with the `mongo` shell (which is the syntax in this question) and make sure that `version()` and `db.version()` both report 3.6 or newer.

Comment: I tested, It only works with `mongo shell`, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @qmn1711 Were you originally using an older version of the `mongo` shell or alternative admin UI?

Comment: I used `Robo 3T 1.2.1`